# How to create a back button to previous page on Android with Titanium Studio?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have created a back button to take me to the previous page. See code bellow:

```
var backbutton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'back',
    bottom: 10,
    left: 10,
    zIndex:2
});
win3.add(backbutton);
```

I add a addEventListener to backbutton. See code bellow:

```
backbutton.addEventListener('click',function() {
    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        url:'alarmgroups.js',
        title:'Sensor/Larm Objekt'
    });
    win.open({modal:true});
    win3.close();
    win3.hide();
});
```

Know I wonder what the problem could be.
When Im using the code above It makes the Application crash.
Im using zIndex on every .js page that I have in my project, but I dont know if Its right to do so.
I use win.open({modal:true}); and after that code I run win3.close(); and win3.hide();. win3 Its my current window.

Does anyone having a solution on how to create a back button for Android?

Answer (score 1):

You have two native solutions to create a back button on android, the first one is adding a back button to the action bar:

To achieve this, you have to edit the android's action bar in the window's open event.
(Note: do not use `modal:true` while opening the window)

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
   title: "test",
   backgroundColor: "white",
});

window.addEventListener('open', function({
   window.activity.actionBar.onHomeIconItemSelected = function() { window.close(); };
   window.activity.actionBar.displayHomeAsUp = true;
});
window.open();
```

The second way, is overriding the android's back button of the current window.

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
   title: "test",
   backgroundColor: "white",
});

window.addEventListener('androidback', function({
    window.close();
});
window.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
title:'Hello world',
backgroundColor:'#fff',
fullscreen:false
});
   win.addEventListener('androidback',function() {
// do something
});
```

Also,here is the link : [Android Back Button in Titanium.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Android_UI_Components_and_Conventions-section-29004929_AndroidUIComponentsandConventions-AndroidBackButton)

Thanks.

Comment: Prior to Release 3.0, the androidback event was named android:back. The older name is now deprecated.

Comment: Yes, you now need to use androidback

Comment: You mean android:back

Comment: No,I mean androidback as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Hi, androidback is not working. I have to use android:back on a Samsung Galaxy 4